# Glossaries Package Taking Ages to Compile

Tags: compiling, glossaries

I've been trying to use the glossaries package but it's taking ages to compile in Overleaf (using LaTeX compiler). Below is a minimum working sample that I built, which still does not compile - please help, thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{achemso}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}



\title{Test}
\author{elifnathan }
\date{April 2019}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Me}
{
    name=Me,
    description={Methyl}
}

\newglossaryentry{DMAPP}
{
    name=DMAPP,
    description={Dimethylallyl diphosphate}
}

\newglossaryentry{MEP}
{
    name=MEP,
    description={Methylerythritol phosphate}
}

\newglossaryentry{MVA}
{
    name=MVA,
    description={Mevalonic}
}

\newglossaryentry{TASY}
{
    name=TASY,
    description={Taxadiene synthethase}
}

\newglossaryentry{Cytochrome P450}
{
    name=Cytochrome P450,
    description={Common proteins that use a variety of molecules as substrates in enzymatic reactions}
}

\newglossaryentry{CCSNC}
{
    name=CCSNC,
    description={Cancer Chemotherapy National Service Center}
}

\newglossaryentry{NCI}
{
    name=NCI,
    description={National Cancer Institue}
}

\newglossaryentry{USDA}
{
    name=USDA,
    description={United States Department of Agriculture}
}

\newglossaryentry{WARF}
{
    name=WARD,
    description={Wisconsin Alumni Research Foundation}
}

\newglossaryentry{IR}
{
    name=IR,
    description={Infrared}
}

\newglossaryentry{UV}
{
    name=UV,
    description={Ultraviolet}
}

\newglossaryentry{INDA}
{
    name=INDA,
    description={Investigational New Drug Application}
}

\newglossaryentry{FDA}
{
    name=FDA,
    description={Food and Drug Administration}
}

\newglossaryentry{DNA}
{
    name=DNA,
    description={Deoxyribonucleic acid}
}

\newglossaryentry{BMS}
{
    name=BMS,
    description={Bristol-Myers Squibb}
}

\newglossaryentry{PCF}
{
    name=PCF,
    description={Plant Cell Fermentation}
}

\newglossaryentry{10-DAB}
{
    name=10-DAB,
    description={10-Deacetylbaccatin III}
}

\newglossaryentry{ICSN}
{
    name=ICSN,
    description={Institut de Chimie des Substances Naturelles}
}

\newglossaryentry{CNRS}
{
    name=CNRS,
    description={Centre National de la Recherche Scientifique}
}

\newglossaryentry{Troc}
{
    name=Troc,
    description={2,2,2-Trichloroethoxycarbonyl chloride}
}

\newglossaryentry{DCC}
{
    name=DCC,
    description={N,N'-Dicyclohexylcarbodiimide}
}

\newglossaryentry{DMAP}
{
    name=DMAP,
    description={4-Dimethylaminopyridine}
}

\newglossaryentry{TMS}
{
    name=TMS,
    description={Trimethylsilane}
}

\newglossaryentry{CRADA}
{
    name=CRADA,
    description={Cooperative research and development agreement}
}

\newglossaryentry{NIH}
{
    name=NIH,
    description={National Institute of Health}
}

\newglossaryentry{NMR}
{
    name=NMR,
    description={Nuclear magnetic resonance spectroscopy}
}

\newglossaryentry{Et}
{
    name=Et,
    description={Ethyl}
}

\newglossaryentry{S\textsubscript{N}2}
{ 
    name=S\textsubscript{N}2,
    description={Nucleophilic Substitution with the rate determining step involving two components}
}

\newglossaryentry{$\Delta$H$^{\ddagger}$}
{
    name=$\Delta$H$^{\ddagger}$,
    description={Enthalpy of activation}
}

\newglossaryentry{$\Delta$S$^{\ddagger}$}
{
    name=$\Delta$S$^{\ddagger}$,
    description={Entropy of activation}
}

\newglossaryentry{Tf}
{
    name=Tf,
    description={Triflate}
}

\newglossaryentry{TLC}
{
    name=TLC,
    description={Thin layer chromatography}
}

\newglossaryentry{LDA}
{
    name=LDA,
    description={Lithium diisopropylamide}
}

\newglossaryentry{R\textsubscript{f}}
{
    name=R\textsubscript{f},
    description={Retardation Factor}
}

\newglossaryentry{HMPA}
{
    name=HMPA,
    description={Hexamethylphosphoramide}
}

\newglossaryentry{Vitamin B\textsubscript{12}}
{
    name=Vitamin B\textsubscript{12},
    description={A water soluble cobalt-based vitamin}
}

\newglossaryentry{JACS}
{
    name=JACS,
    description={Journal of the American Chemical Society}
}

\newglossaryentry{\textit{m}CPBA}
{
    name=\textit{m}CPBA,
    description={\textit{meta}-Chloroperoxybenzoic acid
}
}

\newglossaryentry{DCM}
{
    name=DCM,
    description={Dichloromethane}
}

\newglossaryentry{MOP}
{
    name=MOP,
    description={Methoxypropyl acetal}
}
\newglossaryentry{NMO}
{
    name=NMO,
    description={\textit{N}-Methylmorpholine \textit{N}-oxide
}
}
\newglossaryentry{BOM}
{
    name=BOM,
    description={Benzyloxymethyl acetal}
}
\newglossaryentry{DBU}
{
    name=DBU,
    description={1,8-Diazabicyclo[5.4.0]undec-7-ene}
}
\newglossaryentry{TPAP}
{
    name=TPAP,
    description={Tetrapropylammonium perruthenate}
}
\newglossaryentry{TBS}
{
    name=TBS,
    description={\textit{tert}-butyldimethylsilyl}
}
\newglossaryentry{TSAF}
{
    name=TSAF,
    description={tris(dimethylamino)sulfonium difluorotrimethylsilicate}
}
\newglossaryentry{THF}
{
    name=THF,
    description={Tetrahydrofuran}
}
\newglossaryentry{MEM}
{
    name=MEM,
    description={2-Methoxyethoxymethyl ether}
}

\newglossaryentry{DEM}
{
    name=DEM,
    description={Diethyl malonate}
}
\newglossaryentry{Ms}
{
    name=Ms,
    description={Mesyl}
}

\newglossaryentry{TES}
{
    name=TES,
    description={Triethylsilyl ether}
}

\newglossaryentry{PCC}
{
    name=PCC,
    description={Pyridinium chlorochromate}
}

\newglossaryentry{PDC}
{
    name=PDC,
    description={Pyridinium dichromate}
}

\newglossaryentry{Ts}
{
    name=Ts,
    description={Tosyl}
}

\newglossaryentry{KHMDS}
{
    name=KHMDS,
    description={Potassium bis(trimethylsilyl)amide}
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\clearpage
\glsaddall
\printglossary[nonumberlist]
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document doesn't compile without errors. Don't use stuff like this in glossary keys: `{S\textsubscript{N}2}`, a key should be a simple text and not contain formatting commands.

Comment: Okay - thanks, this appears to work, but I do need to have formatted commands in the glossary, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Sure, in the description and the name you can use formatting commands, only the keys should be keys.

Comment: Thank you so much - this works, you are my hero <3